# When does DatagramSocket.receive() throw IOException?

Tags: java, sockets, ioexception, datagram

I'm creating a server which needs to listen for incoming UDP packages.

My problem is that I don't know how to handle an `IOException` on `DatagramSocket.receive()`. Every tutorial I can find either just print its stack trace and continue or throws it away from the method. No one actually tells me when or why the exception is thrown. Even the Javadoc just states:

```
IOException - if an I/O error occurs when creating the socket.
```

This gives me a hard time answering what I should do in such event.

- Can I safely resume reading the socket?
- Should I close it and try again?
- Should I treat it as a fatal exception and quit everything?

Comment: Are you expecting many such exceptions?  If not, you could just display/log the exception.message, sleep(1000) to prevent runaway exceptions on continual errors, and then try again.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. As I don't know what causes it I don't know what to expect.
If it something that happened under just this receive it would be best to just try again, but if the socket is fried it's better to try to reopen the socket and if I'm shit out of luck the best thing would be to log it and alert someone to come and look at it ASAP.
Of course I could count number of retries and fallback, but I guess it must mean something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It throws `SocketTimeoutException` if you have set a read timeout and it expires. In this circumstance you can just retry. It throws `IOException` if something else is wrong: most of these are fatal to the socket and you must close it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understood that, but are you saying that on IOException I should try to reopen the socket?

Comment: @Pajn No. I can only suggest you read it again. I'm not fond of this 'are you saying' game. In my long experience the answer is invariably 'no'.

Comment: Today I understand the answer, but over a year ago I were very new and troubled with it. Good thing I revisited older questions so that I could accept it now. Better late than never I guess...